# google maps api

Tags: google-maps

I want to have google map on my page and I hope it can be based of a zipcode.example 90001.

I also would like to have the general stuff like the ability to zoom out, zoom in etc.

Where can I get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Map Tutorial:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/introduction.html

Control tutorial:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html